# Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80040E4D): "Invalid authorization specification"

Tags: sql-server, ssis, connection, oledb

From a SQL Server Integration Services 2012 package, I run three Execute SQL Tasks concurrently in a For Loop Container, to check if the following conditions have been met:

- Dependencies met
- Failure occurred
- All steps completed

If all dependencies have been met, and either all steps are completed, or one of the steps failed, the package will continue. Otherwise it will wait for 10 seconds to execute the steps again.

This runs well for quite a while (> 10 minutes), but sometimes it happens that any of the three tasks fails with the aforementioned error.

The ConnectionManager used makes use of a dynamically set datasource and initial catalog. These are being set by Expressions on the CM properties. The ConnectionManager uses Integrated Security using the SQL Server Agent account that executes the package. The Connection Manager has not been set to retain the same connection.

The error does not appear in either the SQL Server log, or the Windows Event Log on the (database server), so it seems to be raised by the provider itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: Set up some logging to help with the debug process.

Comment: Use the OnError handler to return more information about which item failed and why.

Comment: I get all logging through the SSIS Execution reports. So I now what task fails (a different one each time, but raising the same error). What I don't understand, is why it would suddenly fail. Because of the For Loop every 10 second, these three task have each run 60 times successful, but then, somehow, somewhere, the connection becomes corrupt or something.